# Postgresql random slow query

Tags: postgresql, optimization, query-optimization, database-performance

We are having a problem with a specific query that sometimes takes over 620.000 ms on execute, but this is random because if we execute the same query again, it takes aprox. 79ms

This is the query:

```
INSERT INTO product_store(id_store, cod_product, account_id, stock,  product,active) 
SELECT s.id_store, t.cod_product, t.account_id, 0,  i.product, i.active
FROM tmp_import_product t, store s, product i 
WHERE t.id_process_import_product = 99988 
AND s.account_id = t.account_id 
AND s.active = 'S' 
AND i.account_id = t.account_id 
AND i.cod_product = t.cod_product 
AND i.manage_stock = 'S' 
AND i.variant_stock = 'N' 
AND t.existent = 'S' 
AND t.error = 'N' 
AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM product_store i WHERE i.cod_product = t.cod_product AND i.account_id = t.account_id AND i.id_store = s.id_store)
```

And this is the plan

```
Insert on product_store  (cost=1.57..296.01 rows=1 width=733) (actual rows=0 loops=1)
  Buffers: shared hit=532388600 read=21556 dirtied=186
  ->  Nested Loop  (cost=1.57..296.01 rows=1 width=733) (actual rows=0 loops=1)
        Buffers: shared hit=532388600 read=21556 dirtied=186
        ->  Nested Loop  (cost=1.14..291.09 rows=1 width=76) (actual rows=22200 loops=1)
                Join Filter: (t.account_id = s.account_id)
              Buffers: shared hit=74893
              ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.85..290.40 rows=2 width=76) (actual rows=7400 loops=1)
                    Buffers: shared hit=37893
                    ->  Index Scan using ix_tmp_import_product_2 on tmp_import_product t  (cost=0.42..120.32 rows=64 width=21) (actual rows=7400 loops=1)
                            Index Cond: (t.id_process_import_product = '96680'::bigint)
                            Filter: ((t.existent = 'S'::bpchar) AND (t.error = 'N'::bpchar))
                            Rows Removed by Filter: 102
                          Buffers: shared hit=3515
                    ->  Index Scan using pk_product on product i  (cost=0.43..2.66 rows=1 width=64) (actual rows=1 loops=7400)
                            Index Cond: (((i.cod_product)::text = t.cod_product) AND (i.account_id = t.account_id))
                            Filter: ((i.manage_stock = 'S'::bpchar) AND (i.variant_stock = 'N'::bpchar))
                            Rows Removed by Filter: 0
                          Buffers: shared hit=34291
              ->  Index Scan using store_account_id_active_index on store s  (cost=0.28..0.32 rows=2 width=16) (actual rows=3 loops=7400)
                      Index Cond: ((s.account_id = i.account_id) AND (s.active = 'S'::bpchar))
                    Buffers: shared hit=37000
        ->  Index Scan using idx_product_store_account_id_id_store on product_store i_1  (cost=0.43..4.90 rows=1 width=24) (actual rows=1 loops=22200)
                Index Cond: ((i_1.id_store = s.id_store) AND (i_1.account_id = t.account_id))
                Filter: ((i_1.cod_product)::text = t.cod_product)
                Rows Removed by Filter: 141420
              Buffers: shared hit=532306240 read=21556 dirtied=186
Trigger t_insert_product_stock: time=0.000 calls=1
```

I think that because tmp_import_product has a bad estimation, it affects the next joins.
How can I check if the stats of the table are updated? (already check last autovacuum and it is running) How can I improve this query? Could it be something else?

Comment: do you have index in tmp_import_product  ?

Comment: If `tmp_import_product` is populated immediately before running that INSERT, you should run `analyze tmp_import_product;` to update the stats for that table.

Comment: you can get rid of the somewhat costly `and not exists()` if you create a unique constraint on `product_store (cod_product, account_id, id_store)` and use `insert .. on conflict do nothing`

Comment: @Sund'er yes, I have an index, in fact it is being used "ix_tmp_import_product_2"

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name it isn't populated immediately before but it is a long function and that table is updated several times in it, before that insert. Do I have to analyze? Could that analyze affect the performance of the function?

Also, isn't "insert .. on conflict do nothing" costlier than not exists?

Comment: What are your index definitions?

Comment: "Could that analyze affect the performance of the function?"  Of course.  That is why he recommends doing it.

Comment: Why do you have two tables with the same alias "i"?  That is unduly confusing

Comment: @jjanes what I mean by "Could that analyze affect the performance of the function?" is if the analyze part takes longer than the query itself i't wouldn't be useful. Also is it necessary to analyze every time? or should I do it when then number of inserted or modified rows is high?

Comment: Is this a permanent table that just happens to have `tmp` in its name, or is this a temporary table as that term is used by PostgreSQL?  If the latter, autovacuum will never analyze it, as it is only visible to your session.  You will need to manually ANALYZE it however often you decide it needs it.  It shouldn't need it every time you query it if nothing much has changed, but  ANALYZE is usually fast enough that it is better to overdo it than risk under doing it.  That is an empirical question though.

Comment: But in any event, it should be easy enough to just ANALYZE once and see what happens.  If it doesn't fix the problem, no point in worrying about how often to do it, and we can move on to another theory.

Comment: @jjanes it is a regular table that happens to have tmp. I will add analyze to the function, only when the number of rows inserted is more than a certain number, and we will see what happens.

Comment: Also, if it is a table that gets updated a lot of times in the function, would it be better if I insert in a temporary table after all the updates, and then use that table in the later queries?

Comment: `Index Scan using idx_product_store_account_id_id_store on product_store i_1` shows pretty huge buffers hit counter value. Is that expected? If so, could the system be experiencing memory pressure whenever the query is slower than expected? (Note that modern Linux kernel may experience high memory pressure without swapping.)